# Django: setting multiple lists in a view for a template to iterate over

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to create multiple context objects in a view so that I can iterate over them separately in the template and print them vertically as HTML lists. How can I achieve this?

My code is something like this:

views.py:

```
class MultiListView(ListView):

    template_name = os.path.join(APPNAME, "list.html")
    context_object_name = 'list1'
    context_object_name2 = 'list2'
    context_object_name3 = 'list3'

    def get_queryset(self):

        query_set = List.objects.all()
        return list(query_set) # Only sets the context_object_name var, not the rest
```

list.html:

```
{% if list1 %}
  <ul>
   {% for item in list1 %}
    <li class="item-list">item.name</li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}

{% if list2 %}
  <ul>
   {% for item in list2 %}
    <li class="item-list">item.name</li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
{% if list3 %}
  <ul>
   {% for item in list3 %}
    <li class="item-list">item.name</li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

The important thing for me is that the lists are printed vertically, so each list is it's own column. I am aware that the  multiple `context_object_name`'s thing won't work, but I put it in there to demonstrate what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply, you can send three different list in context like this. Is there any speical reason to use ListView for sending three lists?

```
from django.views import View

class MultiListView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        list1 = List.objects.filter(something)
        list2 = List.objects.filter(something)
        list3 = List.objects.filter(something)
        return render(request, 'list.html', {'list1':list1, 'list2':list2, 'list3':list3})
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was trying so hard to make it work with a ListView that I completely brain farted about other ways to do it.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Functional-based View`? NOT `Class-based View`. It will be easy if you use this.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to mix functional-based-views with class-based-views? I have a bunch of other views I'd rather keep as classes.